# Montar notícia agrupando resultados por classe de usuário

Tags: php, mysql

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema de notícias onde uma certa classe de usuário vai poder postar uma ou mais notícias para todos verem ele funciona perfeito, mais para uma melhor visualização gostaria que essas mensagens fossem agrupadas pela classe do usuário que postou. vou dar o exemplo de como está abaixo: 
aqui eu faço um select normal:

```
SELECT a.id_salapostagem, a.titulo, a.mensagem, a.data_lancamento,  
b.descricao
FROM salapostagem a
INNER JOIN usuariotipo b on a.usuariotipo_id = b.id_usuariotipo 
WHERE a.cursograde_id = 0;
```

aqui é a resposta que tenho:

```
id_salapostagem  |        titulo            |                                   mensagem                                             |     descricao
      6          |   teste de mensagem 01   |   teste de mensagem 01 esta mensagem vai aparecer para todo mundo 2015-12-09 16:15:21  |     Webmaster
      7          |   teste de mensagem 02   |   teste de mensagem 02 esta mensagem tbm vai aparecer para todos  2015-12-09 16:19:13  |     Webmaster
      12         |   teste de mensagem 03   |   teste de mensagem 03 esta mensagem vai aparecer para todo mundo 2015-12-09 16:15:21  |     administrador
```

Este é o laço que faço para notícia aparecer

```
<?php
mysql_data_seek($sqlNot, '0');
while($not = mysql_fetch_array($sqlNot) ){
    if($_SESSION["usuariotipoid"] != 4 || $_SESSION["usuariotipoid"] != 5 || $_SESSION["usuariotipoid"] != 9){
    $Botao = "Seção: ".$not["descricao"]."";

}
    ?>
        <div class="nome" style="margin-top: 10px">ADMINISTRAÇÃO<div style="float: right"><?php echo $Botao; ?></div></div>
        <div class="disciplina ocultar" style="margin-top: 10px"><?php echo $not["titulo"]; ?> <div style="float: right"><?php echo $not["data_lancamento"]; ?></div></div>

        <div class="content mostrar" style="min-height: auto;">
            <?php echo $not["mensagem"]; ?>


        </div>  
        <?php
}
```

As notícias aparecem na sequência em que foram postadas dessa forma:

```
| ADMINISTRAÇÃO                                Seção: Webmaster   |
| teste de mensagem 01                       2015-12-09 16:15:21  |
| teste de mensagem 01 esta mensagem vai aparecer para todo mundo |

| ADMINISTRAÇÃO                                Seção: Webmaster   |
| teste de mensagem 02                       2015-12-09 16:19:13  |
| teste de mensagem 02 esta mensagem vai aparecer para todo mundo |

| ADMINISTRAÇÃO                              Seção: administrador |
| teste de mensagem 03                       2015-12-09 16:15:21  |
| teste de mensagem 03 esta mensagem vai aparecer para todo mundo |
```

E eu gostaria que aparecessem assim:

```
| ADMINISTRAÇÃO                                Seção: Webmaster   |
| teste de mensagem 01                       2015-12-09 16:15:21  |
| teste de mensagem 01 esta mensagem vai aparecer para todo mundo |
|                                                                 |
| teste de mensagem 02                       2015-12-09 16:19:13  |
| teste de mensagem 02 esta mensagem vai aparecer para todo mundo |



| ADMINISTRAÇÃO                              Seção: administrador |
| teste de mensagem 03                       2015-12-09 16:15:21  |
| teste de mensagem 03 esta mensagem vai aparecer para todo mundo |
```

Desde já agradeço qualquer ajuda, pois está difícil de resolver isso.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uma das coisas é acrescentar o campo que você quer ordenar no ORDER BY:

```
SELECT   a.id_salapostagem, a.titulo, a.mensagem, a.data_lancamento, b.descricao
FROM     salapostagem a
INNER    JOIN usuariotipo b on a.usuariotipo_id = b.id_usuariotipo 
WHERE    a.cursograde_id = 0
ORDER BY descricao
```

A outra é criar uma situação para mostrar o título uma vez só. Por exemplo algo assim:

```
$titulo= '';

...

while($not = mysql_fetch_array($sqlNot) ){
   if( $titulo!= $not['descricao'] ) {
      echo 'ADMINISTRACAO            Secao: ' . $not['descricao'];
      $titulo=$not['descricao'];
   }
```

Esse é só um exemplo, teria que adequar para o campo correto.