# SELECT no MYSQL agrupado por mes, mas mostrando todos

Tags: mysql, select, group-by

Tenho a seguinte tabela em MYSQL:

```
cavalo - 2016-01-15
cachorro - 2016-01-16
gato - 2016-02-23
coelho - 2016-02-24
ovelha - 2016-03-21
tatu - 2016-03-22
```

Queria dar um SELECT e mostrar dessa forma:

```
JANEIRO - 2016: cavalo cachorro

FEVEREIRO - 2016: gato coelho

MARÇO - 2016: ovelha tatu
```

Eu até tentei com `GROUP BY`, mas aí ele não lista todos de cada mês, alguém tem uma luz?

Comment: Bastaria o ORDER BY YEAR(data), MONTH(data). Se está fazendo isso via alguma linguagem extra (PHP, por exemplo) compensa usar o ORDER BY e apenas formatar na exibição.

Comment: To usando PHP.

Eu detecto quando o mês for diferente do ultimo mês selecionado e trato, é isso que imagina?

Comment: Exato. fora do loop, inicia $mes_atual='';  dentro do loop: if $db_mes == $mes_atual mostra só o bicho, senão $mes_atual = $db_mes e mostra tudo. Pouco código, fácil leitura, sem complicação. Se tiver alguma dificuldade, ponha o loop atual na pergunta e a tag PHP, que eu posto um exemplo.

Comment: Aqui tem uma coisa do tipo (a sua é até bem mais simples): http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105060/

Comment: Você pode "Denormalizar" esta tabela... Mas tudo depende de quantos animais você tem.