# Como agrupar resultados SQL por mês e ano?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Gostaria de saber como posso fazer uma consulta ao banco de dados MySql e agrupar os registros por ano e mês.

---

No momento eu faço primeiro uma consulta para obter os registros de ano, depois para cada ano eu uso um for() para filtrar os resultados por mês dentro daquele ano. Por exemplo:

```
$ano = sql("SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(dataCadastro) as 'ano' FROM tabela");

foreach ($ano as &$row) {
    $ano = $row['ano'];

    for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {
        $item = sql("SELECT id, ... FROM tabela WHERE YEAR(dataCadastro) = '$ano' AND MONTH(dataCadastro) = '$i'");
        $row[$i] = $item;
    }
}
```

Pesquisando sobre o assunto vi que poderia usar `GROUP BY`, mas quando tento usar, a consulta retorna vazia, mesmo tendo certeza de que teria resultados. Por exemplo:

```
$grupo = sql("SELECT id, ... FROM tabela"); //Retorna os dados corretamente
$grupo = sql("SELECT id, ... FROM tabela GROUP BY YEAR(dataCadastro)"); //Retorna vazio
```

A data no banco de dados está como `datetime`, ex.: `2016-11-09 17:30:00`

Existe algum modo de obter esse resultado utilizando o `GROUP BY`? Pois pelas pesquisas que fiz, observei que sim, mas quando tento executar, não consigo obter os resultados.

Lembrando que o primeiro modo que mostrei (com o uso de `foreach`) eu consigo obter os resultados como eu desejo, porém gostaria de simplificar o processo.

Comment: Quando vc usa o `group by` tentou rodar essa consulta direto no banco? qual versão do MySQL vc utiliza?

Comment: @rray segundo o Wamp, essa é a versão: 5.7.14. Quando rodo direto no banco também apresenta erro, é este: `SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by`

Comment: Você está usando PDO?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic sim.

Comment: @CelsomTrindade tem uma forma de fazer que a chave seria o mesano, tipo `["012016"] => [[],[],[]]` os registros ficariam separados por mês e ano dentro de uma chave, é mais ou menos do que precisa?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic se entendi bem, sim. Seria para montar um relatório, então eu preciso separar por ano e mês, onde cada mês contem uma array dos registros correspondentes àquele mês. Do modo como eu fiz no primeiro exemplo de código, eu consigo esse resultado, inclusive gerando uma array vazia caso não haja registros naquele mês.

Comment: Ai você me deu uma informação extra, do jeito que eu ia te passar não teria como gerar o que falta só o que existe na tabela!

Comment: Então deve ser isso, o `group by` do MySQL não é ansi ou seja na maioria dos campos vc é obrigado a agrupar por todas as colunas que estão no select, isso passou a vigorar no MySQL5.7.5 veja na [documenta](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by), acredito que [esse](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34115174/1342547) seja o problema. Como teste tente agrupar por todas as colunas questão no select.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

O `GROUP BY` do MySQL não segue o padrão ansi ou seja na maioria banco de dados existe a obrigatóriedade de agrupar por todos campos que estão na lista de campos (após a palavra  `SELECT`). Essa mudança ocorreu a partir da versão 5.7.5 do MySQL.

Versãos anteriores a 5.7.5

```
SELECT id, nome, email FROM tabela GROUP BY id
```

A partir do 5.7.5 sua consulta deve ficar:

```
SELECT id, nome, email FROM tabela GROUP BY id, nome, email.
```

O nome de configuração é [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) e pode desativada setando a variável `sql_mode`

```
SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

[MySQL - Documentação](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by)

[Disable ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36033983/1342547)

Answer (score 6):

### Sobre o GROUP BY

Se quer usar agregação, é basicamente isso, mas não acredito que é o que você está buscando na realidade, se vai usar todas as linhas para relatório:

```
SELECT
  SUM( `valor` ) AS total
FROM
  datas
GROUP BY
  YEAR( `data` ), MONTH( `data` );
```

Funcionou localmente na versão 5.1.58, e na 5.6 no SQL Fiddle, segue link:

> http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f03c6/1

Para versões de 5.7.5 em diante, observar a flag mencionada na resposta do @rray. Você pode executar um `SELECT @@version;` para saber qual está usando.

### Sobre o problema aparente da pergunta

Se quiser todas as linhas, para agrupar só na saida, por exemplo, por cabeçalhos em PHP separando os blocos, use `ORDER BY` em vez de `GROUP BY`:

```
SELECT
  id, `data`
FROM
  datas
ORDER BY
  YEAR( `data` ), MONTH( `data` );
```

Aí basta um `if` no loop de exibição para mostrar o título somente quando muda o mês e ano. Que é o mesmo problema desta questão aqui, com código de exemplo:

> [Montar notícia agrupando resultados por classe de usuário](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/105060/70)

<sub>(eu nem precisava mencionar isso de tão básico, mas se quiser imprimir os meses vazios, é mera questão de colocar um loop no lugar do `if`)</sub>

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT extract(month FROM nome_campo) mes, extract(year FROM nome_campo) ano
FROM datas
GROUP BY extract(month FROM nome_campo), extract(year FROM nome_campo)
```

Answer (score -1):

A forma mais simples é concatenando o mês e ano:

```
CONCAT( MONTH(data_criacao), '/', YEAR(data_criacao) ) AS data
```

isso vai produzir algo como:

```
10/2021
```