# Mysql retornando erro de "Group By" após atualização para versão 5.7

Tags: mysql

Eu tinha uma determinada consulta MYSQL que estava funcionando corretamente.

Essa é a consulta:

```
SELECT *, count(*) as count FROM `post_hashtags`
WHERE `created_at` BETWEEN ? AND ? 
    AND (SELECT count(*) AS `aggregate` 
FROM `post` 
WHERE `post`.`id` = post_hashtags.post_id 
    AND `status` = 0 
    AND `post_privacidade_id` = 1) >= ? 
GROUP BY `hashtag` 
ORDER BY `count` DESC, created_at DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

Mas após atualizar o Mysql para versão 5.7 na minha máquina, comecei a receber esse erro:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1055 Expression #1 of SELECT list is
>   not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column
>   'post_hashtags.id' which is not functionally dependent
>   on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with
>   sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Alguém sabe o que está acontecendo? Nunca recebi essa mensagem antes.

Tem alguma coisa considerada errada na query, para a nova versão do 
Mysql?

Comment: **Nota**: É bom receber conselhos de refatoração. Sei que minha query não está lá grandes coisas, mas como se trata de um sistema antigo que está sendo mantido, não posso mexer em nada. Só preciso mesmo saber como fazer esse erro parar.

Comment: Talvez seja dup dessa aqui => http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/164495/91

Comment: Em que sentido essa pergunta é duplicada? Onde relata o erro na pergunta linkada?

Comment: [Nesse comentário](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/164495/como-agrupar-resultados-sql-por-m%c3%aas-e-ano#comment338270_164495)

Answer (score 11):

Todos os campos que estiverem no SELECT e não estiverem utilizando funções (como COUNT, SUM, AVG, MAX, MIN, etc.) devem estar na cláusula GROUP BY.

No seu caso, como está utilizando asterisco, deveria ter todos os campos da tabela na cláusula GROUP BY.

Comment: Nossa, mas isso não fica inviável? E por que esse problema ocorre agora e não ocorria antes?

Comment: A versão 5.7 está muito mais sólida e robusta, com padrões mais sólidos. Concordo que é mais chato, mas gosto pela segurança.

Answer (score 10):

Eu resolvi o problema desabilitando o `sql_mode`.

Fiz assim:

```
mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

De acordo com essa resposta do [SOEN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23921117/disable-only-full-group-by)