# Exibir maior valor e o nome

Tags: php, html, mysql

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
    <?php
    $consulta = mysql_fetch_assoc(mysql_query('SELECT MAX(pontos) FROM usuarios'));
    echo  intval($consulta['MAX(pontos)']);
?>
```

Porém, ele só exibe o maior valor, eu queria que exibisse o nome de quem o possui também.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou selecionar o primeiro registro ordenando-os de forma decrescente? Algo como `SELECT ... FROM usuarios ORDER BY pontos DESC LIMIT 1`.

Comment: É porque não seria na mesma divisória. Ele teria uma divisória própria, por exemplo: MAIOR PONTUADOR: .. Daí viria as informações, sabe?

Comment: Não. Qual a relação dessa "divisória" com o SQL?

Comment: Divisória me referi a "div" de HTML, desculpe pela irreverência...

Comment: Já tentou: `SELECT login, MAX(pontos) FROM usuarios`

Comment: Sam, sou bem leigo em PHP mesmo. Como faria isso, por favor?

Comment: E se houverem mais de um usuário com a mesma pontuação máxima? Deve ser retornado todos eles? Se não, qual deve ser o critério para definir qual será retornado?

Comment: Seguinte, com versão 8 testei assim `SELECT nome, MAX(pontos) as maior FROM usuarios group by id limit 1` e deu resultado certinho!  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ch7WYBguAY3jo9QMZnpLpL/0

Comment: @LeoCaracciolo Deu certinho por coincidência. Altere o valor de Beltrano para 198 e rode, vai retornar o Fulano novamente.

Comment: Não, não sei o porquê da desmarcação.

Comment: é que vc só pode marcar apenas 1 resposta. Se marcar a outra, a que foi marcada anteriormente é desmarcada.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usando mysqli:

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $base);
$consulta = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($conn, 'SELECT login, MAX(pontos) as maior FROM usuarios'));
echo intval($consulta['maior']); // imprime "125"
echo $consulta['login']; // imprime "teste2"
```

No SELECT você informa as colunas que quer retornar separadas por vírgula, e no `MAX(pontos)` você cria um alias (no caso coloquei `maior`).

### Edição

Um problema bem observado pelo amigo *Anderson Carlos Woss* no que se refere às versões a partir do 5.7 do MySQL e que é abordado [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/164618/8063) e [nesta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/164515/8063).

Se estiver usando uma versão 5.7 ou maior, use a query:

```
SELECT login, pontos FROM usuarios
WHERE pontos = (SELECT MAX(pontos) FROM usuarios)
```

**[Teste no DBFiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9HzHyDPnX1psNV6zcX6j3M/0)**

Comment: Em que versão do MySQL você testou? Nas versões 5.7 e 8.0 que testei deram erro pela falta do `group by`.

Comment: Cara, testei numa hospedagem da Locaweb... vou buscar aqui qual versão....

Comment: A versão é 5.6.

Comment: Se quiser testar: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/mwpuGfsMfkhCjSAZLqbYVq/0

Comment: Solução que encontrei: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9HzHyDPnX1psNV6zcX6j3M/0

Comment: Essa é a melhor principalmente se considerar vários registros com o valor máximo.

Answer (score 2):

**MySQL obsoleto: não utilize funções mysql_***

A biblioteca MySQL, que conta com funções como mysql_connect, mysql_query e semelhantes, não permite utilizar recursos novos do MySQL, como triggers, stored procedures e outros. Esses recursos só estão disponíveis com o uso da biblioteca MySQLi.

A extensão MySQLi existe desde o PHP 5.0, que foi lançado em 13 de julho DE 2004. Desde então, já era recomendado usar MySQLi em vez de MySQL.

Porém, muitos programadores continuaram usando (e utilizam até hoje) a biblioteca MySQL.

Para mudar esse cenário, a equipe do PHP tomou uma atitude um tanto drástica: removeu a biblioteca MySQL do PHP 7.

> Alternativas à extensão MySQL

1. Usar a extensão MySQLi em vez da MySQL.
2. Usar a extensão PDO (PHP Data Object).

**Exemplo usando PDO**

> **funciona em qualquer versão do MySQL** -  [teste aqui](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/sFozsutXrMG7u7HAgXTqX7/0)

```
/******************** conexão *********************************************
$hostname="localhost";  
$username="USUARIO";  
$password="SENHA";  
$db = "Nome_BD";  
$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=$db", $username, $password);
**************************************************************************/

$sql= "SELECT login, pontos FROM usuarios order by pontos DESC limit 1"; 
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$obj = $stmt->fetchObject();
echo $obj->login;
echo $obj->pontos;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, Léo.